# Contain variable size images within box, maintain proportions, fill box

Tags: html, css

Im listing images in landscape 10:7 and portrait 7:10 in a grid.

The images all have these proportions, but some are small and some are big.

I want to list them in a grid 3 images wide and I want all images to be displayed at the same size. It is important that I maintain the proportions. The images also have a css border.

[image: the target]

I have a solution using the padding-bottom trick where I set the **a** tag to be square and then absolute position the **img** inside it. This works but when the images are small, they wont scale up. If I set the width or height of the image, the proportions are screwed up.

The first two images are too small and does not fill the box:
[image: The first two images are too small and does not fill the box]

The html is generated for me (I cant change it) and looks as follows:

```
<li>
  <a>
    <img srcset="">
  </a>

  other stuff like title and description
</li>
```

I also tried using object-fit to contain the images within the square **a** tag - this does not work for me because the images have a css border applied to them, this border would then become square.

Comment: As you can't use object fit, then you are going to need a bit of js to figure out if the image is landscape or portrait and then if landscape, add width 100% and if portrait add height 100%, there is no pure css way to do this

Comment: try min-width and min-height on the image

Comment: Thanks Pete, I will look into:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38430194/add-different-classes-to-vertical-or-horizontal-img

Comment: @CarolMcKay that won't work - you still wouldn't be able to tell whether it needed a min width or a min height and if you added both, then it wouldn't keep it's aspect ratio

Answer (score 0):

As [Pete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1790982/pete) pointed out, there is no way using pure css to solve my problem. I need to use some technique to determine if the image is landscape or portrait.

My final solution is a jQuery script that detects and adds classes to the images.

CSS:

```
.landscape {
  width: 100%;
}
.portrait {
  height: 100%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
window.onload = function () {
  var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

  for( var i=0; i<images.length;i++){
    if (images[i].naturalWidth > images[i].naturalHeight) {
      $(images[i]).addClass('landscape');
    } 
    else{ 
      if(images[i].naturalWidth < images[i].naturalHeight) {
        $(images[i]).addClass('portrait');  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Add different classes to VERTICAL or HORIZONTAL img](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38430194/add-different-classes-to-vertical-or-horizontal-img)